# Finding number of pages printed by year

Tags: printing, printer

Is there a way to do this? I've been tasked with finding out how many pages our printers printed in 2019, and finding the total pages printed since each printer *came into use* has generally been no issue, but I'm not finding much at all for getting exact totals by year.

Notably, we're using a variety of printers, but mostly Toshiba and Lexmarks.

Comment: Most office/commercial printers have stats you can pull, but they'll be model specific. You'll need to search on each model and find out how to print a status page.

Comment: They do have stats, but none of the stats in question are about page counts per year. For example, I'm accessing a Toshiba printer by IP, and there's a counter page , with total counts for number of pages, color pages, printing, scanning, etc.; there's nothing to segregate this information by year.

Comment: If you've kept records about how many pages were printed on the machine in years past, you can subtract the previous years and get a good idea of how many were printed this last year. Unfortunately, most machines don't keep records that are timestamped like that.

Answer (score 0):

Average pages printed per toner cartridge multiplied by number of toner cartridges purchased in that year = rough estimated page count per printer type.

If you didn't record that historical data and the printer doesn't log it, that's the least worst solution.